# How to get id/params to redux action from react Router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Currently i have a listing page of objects. I want to display the detail page of a single object (Things are all done with Reactjs). The listing objects have a Link like this:

```
<Link to={'/detail/'+this.props.data.id} >Read more</Link>
```

Onclicking the Link, it points to another page where i want to display all details of that particular object. The Details of that particular object is fetched from http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/songs/**55**, where 55 is the id of object. I'm using **Redux to fetch data from API**.

ListingPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Link to={'/detail/'+this.props.data.id} >Read more</Link>                      
        </div>
      );
   }
}
export default List
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import List from './ListPage.js'; 
import Detail from './Detail.js'

class Home extends React.Component {    
     render(){      
       return(
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
                <Route path="/detail/:number" component={Detail} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
 }
 export default Home
```

Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Detail extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div>{**display details here**}</div>
        )
    }
} 
export default Detail
```

Currently onclicking the Link, it points to another page, but no details are displayed. I don't know how to get the id from the Link url in react-redux. Please help me. (Seriously i must use Redux)

Comment: So you want to get `id` from `<Link to={'/detail/'+this.props.data.id}` ? and pass it to the react-redux , to manage the state ?

Comment: yes, on clicking the Link, currently the page loads without any data. but i want that page to have data. (Like any listing and detail page function)

Comment: can you post `details` component code ?

Comment: From the API, i will get name, description, etc. there are nothing more complex things.

Comment: what i understood is you want to get that id and pass it to the API to make the request and display name , description etc ?

Comment: exactly thats it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166600/discussion-between-aaqib-and-piyal-george).

Comment: Thanks Aaqib, Did exactly as you said., and it worked

Comment: Glad it worked good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mapStateToProps` to read route parameters which are passed to your component by `react-router`. Your `:number` named param will be available at `ownProps.match.params.number`, which you will need to pass into your component.

Your component will then pass it to your action creator for loading the data.

More details are in comments:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Detail extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        // When the component mounts 
        // call your action creator to load the details, 
        // if songDetails are not already available
        if (!this.props.songDetails) 
            this.props.loadSongDetails(this.props.songId);
    }

    render() {
        // Don't show anything until songDetails are loaded
        // Optionally, you can also show a loading screen for better user experience
        if (!this.props.songDetails) return null;

        // Once songDetails are loaded, you can use `this.props.songDetails` to populate your UI
        return (
            <div>{this.props.songDetails}</div>
        )
    }
}

/**
 * 'mapStateToProps' gets a second parameter which contains the props passed directly to the component
 * In this case, react-router will pass route parameters to it.
 * Route parameters will include your named parameter ":number" at "match.params.number".
 * You can pass this parameter into your component, and later pass it into your loading function.
 *
 * "getSongDetails" is a selector function which gets the songDetails from your redux store.
 */
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    songId: ownProps.match.params.number,
    songDetails: getSongDetails(state)
});

/**
 * Use 'mapDispatchToProps' to pass your action creator into your component.
 * This action creator will be called with songId when the component loads.
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadSongDetails: (songId) => dispatch(loadSongDetailsActionCreator(songId))
});

/**
 * Use Redux's "connect" HOC to pass props into your component.
 */
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Detail);
```

Comment: Can you show the code for getSongDetails and loadSongDetailsActionCreator?

Comment: That implementation would be specific to your application. `getSongDetails` simply reads state and returns the song details. You would also pass the ID to the function, unless it is supposed to get the ID from the state itself. `loadSongDetailsActionCreator` would simply make an API call to the server to load the relevant data. Hope this helps.